# How to disable anPHP disable and clear textbox when checkbox is unchecked. Check/uncheck checkbox depending on database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to disable and clear a textbox if a checkbox is uncheck and enable it when checked. At the same time, the checkbox should be dependent on the value on the database.

- If `deductstatus == 1`, checkbox should be checked when loaded
- If `deductstatus == 2`, checkbox should be unchecked when loaded

The code below is not working. Any help?

```js
$(".dedstat").click(function() {
  if ($(".dedstat").is(":checked")) {
    $(".deductto").removeAttr("disabled")
  } else {
    $(".deductto").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    var deductto = document.getElementById("deductto");
    deductto.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat" value="<?php if ($dedstat == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>">
<input type="text" name="deductto" id="deductto" value="<?php echo $deductto;?>">
```

Comment: You use dedstat as a class in your selector , in your HTML it is an id

Comment: You are using `class` selector and on the checkbox you set the `id` dedstat. Same happens with the textbox selector

Comment: tried to change class="dedstat", still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When manipulating boolean attributes such as `checked`, `disabled`, `multiple`, you should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` or `.removeAttr()`. Some other suggested improvements:

- Use `this.checked` instead of `$(".dedstat").is(":checked")`, so that it is context specific
- Use the ID selector instead of class
- You can chain your jQuery methods, so you can both disable the input and empty its value at the same time
- Listen to the `change` event instead of `click` for `<input>` elements

```js
$("#dedstat").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#deductto").prop("disabled", false)
  } else {
    $("#deductto")
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat">
<input type="text" name="deductto" id="deductto">
```

If you want the state of the input to be evaluated on pageload, you will also have to perform the same logic without binding it to the `onChange` event. The best way is to create a function that is called by both the `onChange` event and DOMready/window.load event. In the example below, the method we create will accept a DOM node as an argument, so that it is contextually aware of which checkbox element you are referring to:

```js
// Method to conditionally enable/disable input
var updateTextInput = function(el) {
  if (el.checked) {
    $("#deductto").prop("disabled", false)
  } else {
    $("#deductto")
      .prop("disabled", true)
      .val('');
  }
}

// Call method when change event is fired from checkbox
$("#dedstat").change(function() {
  updateTextInput(this);
});

// Call method on DOMready, pass DOM node (not the jQuery object)
updateTextInput($('#dedstat')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat">
<input type="text" name="deductto" id="deductto">
```

And with regards to your PHP, you can simply use tenary operators to conditionally write the `checked` prop to your input element, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat" <?php echo $dedstat == 1 ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked is not a value, it is an attribute, it should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat" value="" <?php if ($dedstat == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` attribute can not be used to keep it `checked` or `unchecked` based on database value. And bind checked or unchecked attribute separately.
So change that tag like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dedstat" id="dedstat" onclick="isChecked()" value="1" <?php echo (isset($dedstat) && $dedstat == 1)? "checked" : "" ; ?>
```

More on this, 
If you want to store 1 and 2 values to save checked and unchecked condition of the checkbox respectively, then what you should do is, if the checkbox is checked, you will get its value in php $_POST but if it was not checked, you will not get it in $_POST. So in that case, you should store its default value 2 into the DB column. So then only you can get 2 when you fetch its value next time from DB.

Comment: Thank you for that, now the checkbox is checked when deductionstatus==1, but still when I tried to uncheck, the textbox was not disabled and cleared. Seems something wrong with my script @Himanshu Upadhyay

Comment: @codeseeker, you have accepted one answer, so you got your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little suggestion :
Is your JS  at the bottom of the page ?

Plus I just noticed something :

$(".dedstat") <= you're calling a class with the dot. Your imputs have ID's.

```
$("#dedstat").click(function () {
    if ($("#dedstat").is(":checked")) {
        $("#deductto")
            .removeAttr("disabled")
    }
    else {
        $("#deductto")
            .attr("disabled", "disabled")
            var deductto = document.getElementById("deductto"); 
            .deductto.value = "";
    }
});
```

It should work a little better.

Comment: Yes it is at the bottom of the page. should the input have an onClick attribute? @Corentin Petit

Comment: There is no need to add any onclick in your input, because of this :
$("#dedstat").click(function (). It adds a onclick unction on the "dedstat" input.